# How to set geth variable

Tags: path, ethereum

Could someone please tell me how to change geth variable in Linux?

It's currently:

```
which geth
/usr/bin/geth
```

But I need to make it:

```
/home/kapoor13/quorum/build/bin/geth
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build it from source and then move the executable file in the folder you want, look at [geth documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installing-Geth#build-it-from-source-code). Otherwise you can also set an alias but this has limitations...

Answer (score 0):

One way is creating a symbolic link to the other path.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/geth /usr/bin/geth.old
sudo ln -s /home/kapoor13/quorum/build/bin/geth /usr/bin/geth
```

Anytime you want to recover the original geth just

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/geth.old /usr/bin/geth
```